# Separate entries in xsl for futher passing and altering in php

Tags: javascript, php, xslt

```
<xsl:for-each select="items/item[itemStatus='in_progress']">
        <div style="background-color: #00ccff; border: 2px solid black; padding-bottom: 10px; margin-bottom: 15px; width: 500px; padding-left: 20px">
        <p><b>Item ID: </b><xsl:value-of select="./itemID" /></p>
        <p><b>Item Name: </b><xsl:value-of select="./itemName" /></p>
        <p><b>Category: </b><xsl:value-of select="./category" /></p>
        <p><b>Buy It Now Price: </b><xsl:value-of select="./BINPrice" /></p>
        <p><b>Bid Price: </b><xsl:value-of select="./startPrice" /></p>
        <p><b>Duration: </b><xsl:value-of select="./duration" /></p>
        <button type="button" style="margin-right: 10px" onclick="updateXML()">Place Bid</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="">Buy It Now</button>
        </div>
</xsl:for-each>
```

After formatting the xml with the code above I get the following result:
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUHl1.jpg)

Everything's cool. Next step I want to change the "Bid Price" by taking the input with prompt(), passing it to php and update the old "Bid Price" in .xml to the new one from prompt().
The code in php:

```
<?php
    // preparing xml file
    session_start();
    $xmlFile = "auction.xml";
    $doc = new DOMDocument("1.0");
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $doc->formatOutput = true;

     //update details
    $customerID = $_SESSION['use'];
    $newBid = $_REQUEST['newBid'];

    $unique = true;



    if (($unique == true))
    {
        $xmlFile = "auction.xml";
        $doc = new DOMDocument("1.0");
        $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $doc->formatOutput = true;
        $doc->load($xmlFile);
        $thedocument = $doc->documentElement;

        $item = $doc->getElementsByTagName("item");
        $items = $doc->getElementsByTagName("items")->item(0);

          // checking each customer in xml file
         foreach($item as $node)
        {
            $XMLcustomerID = $node->getElementsByTagName("customerID");
            $XMLcustomerIDValue = $XMLcustomerID->item(0)->nodeValue;

            $XMLstartPrice = $node->getElementsByTagName("startPrice");
            $XMLstartPriceValue = $XMLstartPrice->item(0)->nodeValue;

            $XMLcustomerID->item(0)->nodeValue = $customerID;
            $XMLstartPrice->item(0)->nodeValue = $newBid;
            $saveXML =  $doc->save($xmlFile);
        }
    }
?>
```

As you might have already understood it changes "Bid price" values of all entries in xml but not just the one where I clicked "Place Bid".
**What should I change in my code to be able to change only specific entry's Bid Price value?**

Comment: How is PHP supposed to know which Bid Price was clicked?

Comment: That's a good question :) I don't know how to make it know which button is pressed. The only idea I have is to also ask for "itemID" with prompt(). And then in php I can write something like: change values where ID is *the one specified with prompt()*. But I don't wanna use this method because I'll get my marks deducted for this assignment.

Comment: You should probably pass the itemID as a parameter to "UpdateXml", like so; `<button type="button" style="margin-right: 10px" onclick="updateXML({itemId})">`. Then you can then save it in a hidden field allowing it to be sent to the server in the form submit. Note the use of curly braces is known as an [Attribute Value Template](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-value-templates).

Comment: @TimC Thanks, I'll try that!